# How to escape html code data while inserting data into a table of Hive

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I need to insert data into one of my table column which is having special characters like < > - .....
So I have given \ which is the used as a escaping character for each literal

This is the data for the column "Introduction" i want to insert. 
Data is coming from csv file where all the data will be enclosed in double quotes

```
"<p><span style=""font-family: \'Calibri Light\': sans-serif\; font-size: xx-large\; color: #2184c2\;""><span style=""font-size: 28pt\;""><span style=""font-size: x-large\;""><span style=""font-size: 18pt\;""><strong>Help us improve by taking our short satisfaction survey.&nbsp\;</strong></span></span></span></span></p>"
```

When I tried to insert this data, I am getting below error.

```
AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:\n...","","<p><span style="font-family: \\\\\'Calibri Light\\\\\'...\n                             ^\nEncountered: -\nExpected: CROSS, FROM, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, OFFSET, ON, ORDER, RIGHT, STRAIGHT_JOIN, TABLESAMPLE, UNION, USING, WHERE, COMMA\n\nCAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error\n (110) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

LOG TYPE  -  INFO log

Can someone please help me in inserting this kind data to table

Comment: You wants to avoid inserting the whole sentence if there is a Special character in it?

Comment: One of my columns data is having a lot of special characters, when I try to insert this data into table its giving error as special characters is there. In order to insert this data without any error I need a best solution.

Comment: Please add some sample data from your source table. Also add datatype you have in your source and destination table's column.

Comment: This is the data i am trying to add into the column introduction  "<p><span style=""font-family: 'Calibri Light', sans-serif; font-size: xx-large; color: #2184c2;""><span style=""font-size: 28pt;""><span style=""font-size: x-large;""><span style=""font-size: 18pt;""><strong>Help us improve by taking our short satisfaction survey&nbsp;</strong></span></span></span></span></p>"

Comment: column name will be "Introduction" and datatype is string

Comment: Please make it easy by adding details with the question. Reading details in comments section is really hard to understand. :)

Comment: I Have updated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon and single quotes need to be escaped using backslash:

```
create table test_str as select '<p><span style=""font-family: \'Calibri Light\', sans-serif\; font-size: xx-large\; color: #2184c2\;""><span style=""font-size: 28pt\;""><span style=""font-size: x-large\;""><span style=""font-size: 18pt\;""><strong>Help us improve by taking our short satisfaction survey&nbsp\;</strong></span></span></span></span></p>';

 select * from test_str;
```

Result:

```
<p><span style=""font-family: 'Calibri Light', sans-serif; font-size: xx-large; color: #2184c2;""><span style=""font-size: 28pt;""><span style=""font-size: x-large;""><span style=""font-size: 18pt;""><strong>Help us improve by taking our short satisfaction survey&nbsp;</strong></span></span></span></span></p>
```

Comment: Yes , I just wanted to know is there any way to escape whole line instead of using \ for the special characters. SO that whatever sepcial charcaters comes in the middle of the line  that will be escaped automatically

Comment: It is not possible. Semicolon breaks the line in Hive. The same issue with single quote. You can do it before putting in Hive probably. But in the hive CLI it should be already escaped

Comment: @DppriyaReddy  If the column value is taken from anothe column valye - you can apply some escaping for the whole string. But for literals it is not possible

Comment: when I am trying to enclose whole value in double quotes its not working

Comment: @DppriyaReddy  It wil not work in such way. Semicolon for example means end of the command. It is not possible to escape the whole string. Semicolon breaks the command. You can apply some transformation if the data comes from select like this: `regexp_replace(original_string,'\\;','\\\\\;')` But I do not know how this will help you, it seems you are using literals, this is not possible to escape the whole literal string by enclosing it in some quotes or applying function, literal should contain characters already escaped. You can apply function like regexp_replace to the column not literal

Comment: @DppriyaReddy Though you decided to unaccept my answer, I did my best to explain why you can't escape the whole literal string

Comment: I am so new to this stackoverflow, I thought you cannot see my comment if I accept the answer thats the reason I have unchecked ;-(

Comment: I have changed the error in my question , can you have a look at it.

Comment: @DppriyaReddy But is is the same escaping problem

Comment: @DppriyaReddy Your usage scenario is not clear. How many such rows are you inserting, How are you inserting exactly, Please provide more details and definitely we will find some solution